# Finding a string in comma seperated column with excel vba

Tags: excel

with Excel VBA , I have to search for a specific  Partnumber in a selected column. The Column has Partnumbers separated by a comma.
The data in column is something like this

> Column A
>
> ab,ca,ade,ar
>
> ad,aw,dr ...

When I do a Selection.Find on that column for "ad" , it returns the first row having 'ade'
cannot do a find for Whole cell as there are more than 1 part number in any cell on that column
Here is code I use to do that task .

```
Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:=:"ad", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)  ' This is BUG that needs correction for xlPart

If Cell Is Nothing Then
        ….
End If
```

What is best and efficient way of solving this issue

Thanks for help in advance ...:)

Comment: Read the column as : 1st Row - ab,ac,ade ; 2nd Row ac,ar,fc, 3rd Row:;;;;;;

Comment: how about find `ad,`?

Comment: the partnumber can be anywhere in that cell - it can ar,ae,ade that is without ending in comma

Comment: You can use `RegExp` in this case instead of Excel's `FIND` method where pattern can be `\bad\b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RegExp` based function like below

```
Public Function blCheckString(InputRange As Range, strChkString) As Boolean
Dim objRgEx As Object
Set objRgEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With objRgEx
    .Pattern = "\b" & strChkString & "\b"
    If .Test(InputRange.Value) Then
        blCheckString = True
    Else
        blCheckString = False
    End If
End With
Set objRgEx = Nothing
End Function
```

This can then be used in the code as below.

```
Sub Test()
If blCheckString(Selection, "ad") Then
    MsgBox "Success"
Else
    MsgBox "No Success"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MaheshSubramaniam, please then mark it as answer and up-vote.